# Radio button and radio button grooup on Adober Air for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air, flash-builder

I'm developing an Adobe Air application for Android using ActionScript 3.0 (I'm not using Flex).

I'm trying to use radio buttons and a radio button group, but they aren't available on ActionScript mobile.

I'm using **Flash Builder 4.5.1 Standard** and when I want to `import fl.controls` it complains saying that it isn't available.

Is there any other control that I can use instead of radio buttons?

Comment: "aren't available on ActionScript mobile" can you elaborate exact meaning?

Comment: @nik: read its following paragraph.

Comment: fl.controls is not available in Flash Builder. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why the flash controls do not run in your ENV. But here are two threads collecting alternatives to the Flex and Flash ones:

[GUI Framework for flash (as3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265476/gui-framework-for-flash-as3)

[ActionScript3 User Interface Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141024/actionscript3-user-interface-components)